# Linear Algebra: Inner vs Dot Product

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, inner-products

Please confirm/correct my reasoning:

Given an inner product defined for a vector space, the inner product can be computed using vectors such as functions, polynomials, vectors in R^n. The inner product can be an integral, dot product, etc, depending on the vector space.

Inner products can also be computed using the coordinates of vectors through the Gram Matrix. Either method of computation results in the same answer.

If the basis for the vector space is orthonormal, then any inner product of vectors can be computed using the dot product of coordinates of the vectors.

The usual definition of dot product in R^n only works if the basis is orthonormal, and if the basis is not orthonormal then the Gram Matrix must be used (since it does not equal the identity matrix).

Similar remark can be made for Euclidean Norm. The standard definition of Euclidean norm only works for orthonormal basis but not for non-orthonormal basis. Not sure how to calculate the norm in latter case.

Reason for asking:

I get tripped up while using the usual definition of dot product in R^n.

Usual definition: [x1 ... xi] * [y1 ... yi]' where xi, yi are the coordinates of the vectors x, y.

Using orthonormal basis vs non-orthonormal basis yields different answers.

It seems that the above definition works if you know what x and y are (in the absolute sense).

For example, if I know x = [1 2 3] and y = [1 1 1] then dot product = 6. Then if I represent the vectors in the standard (unit vector) basis then dot product = 6. Lastly if I represent the vectors in a non-orthonormal basis and use the Gram matrix correctly I get dot product = 6.

Basically definitions of inner products and norms such as dot product and Euclidean norm are given in terms of coordinates of vectors, and sometimes the answers don't match depending on the basis of the vector space, and I am trying to rationalize why.

Comment: Everything sounds good, except I don't understand what you are trying to say in the last paragraph. If you change the basis, the coordinates of the vectors will change, but the gram matrix will also change in such a way that the inner product remains the same.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant to say was that in intro to linear algebra or physics classes sometimes the usual definition of dot product (see definition in "reason for asking" part of question) is given, which only worked for me when basis is orthonormal. If I tried to use the definition for a non-orthonormal basis, the vector's coordinates change but the answer also changes (when it shouldn't).

Comment: The inner product is the fundamental thing, which does not change. The dot product is just a computational tool, which can be used to compute the inner product when the basis is orthonormal. If the basis changes, the dot product will change. Sometimes people say "dot product" to mean the Euclidean inner product, because the dot product is used to compute the Euclidean inner product when vectors are expressed in the standard basis.

Comment: Makes sense! Thanks a bunch

Comment: Usually an inner product is defined without referencing any basis at all.

Comment: Is R^n an exception? Inner products for R^n are expressed in coordinates from what I have seen, which then implies basis.

Comment: I think this comes from the fact that when we talk about $\mathbb{R}^n$, we usually implicitly have a basis in mind. If we think of $\mathbb{R}^n$ as sequences of length $n$, the the standard orthonormal basis very naturally falls out. You can also think of $\mathbb{R}^n$ as functions from $\{1,\dots,n\}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, in which case you would define the inner product as an intergral against a counting measure.

Comment: Often infinite dimensional Hilbert spaces are presented as function spaces and its natural to use an inner product defined by an integral. But, for example the space of continuous functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ is separable, hence isomorphic to $\ell^2$, and the inner product in $\ell^2$ is defined similarly to the inner product in $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Choosing the isomorphism from the function space to the sequence space gives you your basis though, so again you just have implicitly chosen a basis (in a sense) when you work with sequences.